# c# label on form not reflecting text change

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2019

OK, I am trying to help someone with a C# winform app for a dice roller. The code below is what they have done to get a basic test structure working - I suspect they don't have much experience with classes yet. Anyway the problem is that the text change for label1 is never updated on the form and I don't understand why.
Any suggestions?

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Dice_Roller
{
  public partial class Form1 : Form
  {
    public Form1()
    {
      InitializeComponent();
    }
    public void DiceOne()
    {
      label1.Text = "test";
    }
    public void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
      Form1 doIt = new Form1();
      doIt.DiceOne();
      label1.Refresh();
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: You're calling `DiceOne()` on a new instance of the form that was never shown. Either remove that instance (i.e., `doIt`) and simply call `DiceOne();` (AKA `this.DiceOne();`) or call `doIt.Show();` to show the new form instance. Moreover, `label1.Refresh()` is redundant here.

Comment: Are you saying that when you load the form, that the lable1 doesn't display the string "test"?

Comment: @AhmedAbdelhameed SUPERB and so obvious - just call DiceOne(); works perfectly. Thanks Ahmed :)

Answer (score 1):

Just use like this, it should work.

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Form1 doIt = new Form1();
        DiceOne();  //change here
    }
```

Comment: Why are you still creating a form that isn't used? I suggest you remove that line. Also fix the indentation.

Comment: @BentTranberg Oh! I just copy the function and try it to work, the line should be remove right!